# Adobe Acrobat Related dropdown list

Tags: excel, adobe, acrobat

I have drop down list in acrobat, I want that when a specific item is selected on that list, it fills out a corresponding description of said item. is this possible?
See Image below for clearer explanation.
[related drop down menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtGZS.png)

Answer (score 0):

This can be (relatively) easily done by inserting a table of the data (as document-level script), and load the dropdown with the element to show as face value, and the index in the table as return value.

Have a closer look at the Acrobat JavaScript documentation.